# Colorbox too wide when opened

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

I have a colorbox that is displaying about twice as wide as the css instructs it too.  An example is [here](http://www.wesleywoodsiowa.org/photo_gallery.php?catid=5).  Click on any of the images, and you will see the box is about twice the size it should be.  This is the same in FF and IE.  There is nothing in [the css](http://www.wesleywoodsiowa.org/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.css) that has a width of 1200.  Why would it be doing this?

This is where I give the colorbox code.

```
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox/colorbox.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
    $("a[rel='example1']").colorbox();
    $("a[rel='example2']").colorbox({transition:"fade"});
    $("a[rel='example3']").colorbox({transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
    $("a[rel='example4']").colorbox({slideshow:true});
    $(".example5").colorbox();
    $(".example6").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
    $(".example7").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true});
    $(".example8").colorbox({width:"50%", inline:true, href:"#inline_example1"});
    $(".example9").colorbox({
        onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
        onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
        onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
        onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
        onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
    });

    //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
    $("#click").click(function(){
        $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the code that makes the picture that is shown in the colorbox.

```
<div class="gallerywrap_1">
    <a href="<?=$pic2?>" title="<?=$caption?>" rel="example3">
        <div class="gallery_1">
            <div class="galleryimg_1" style="background-image: url(<?=$pic?>)"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colorbox javascript is setting the width in relation to the screen resolution.
/size

```
$("a[rel='example3']").colorbox({transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
```

Try changing this to a pixel width or bring the percentage width down.

Hopefully this helps.